# Returning a top level domain with a period at the end in php

Tags: php, dns, return

Basically the problem I am having is I need to write this function that can take a URL like www.stackoverflow.com and just return the "com". But I need to be able to return the same value even if the URL has a period at the end like "www.stackoverflow.com." 
This is what I have so far. The if statement is my attempt to return the point in the array before the period but I dont think I am using the if statement correctly. Otherwise the rest of the code does exactly what is supposed to do.

```
<?php
    function getTLD($domain)
    {

    $domainArray = explode("." , $domain);
    $topDomain = end($domainArray);
       if ($topDomain == " ")
       $changedDomain = prev(end($domainArray));
       return $changedDomain;

    return $topDomain;


    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex for simple cases like that, it is cpu costly and unreadable. Just remove the final dot if it exists:

```
function getTLD($domain) {
    $domain = rtrim($domain, '.');
    return end(explode('.', $domain));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions for something like this. Try this:

```
function getTLD($domain) {
    return preg_replace("/.*\.([a-z]+)\.?$/i", "$1", $domain );
}
```

A live example: http://codepad.org/km0vCkLz

Read more about regular expressions and about how to use them: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

The `end` function is returning an empty string `""` (without any spaces).  You are comparing `$topDomain` to single space character so the `if` is not evaluating to true.

Also `prev` function requires array input and `end($domainArray)` is returning a string, so, `$changedDomain = prev(end($domainArray))` should throw an `E_WARNING`.

Since `end` updates the internal pointer of the array `$domainArray`, which is already updated when you called `$topDomain = end($domainArray)`, you do not need to call `end` on `$domainArray` inside the `if` block.

Try:

```
if ($topDomain == "") {
   $changedDomain = prev($domainArray);
   return $changedDomain; // Will output com
}
```

Here is the [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rec-7sa) for it.